# configuring linux console email client to check attachments

Tags: linux, email, imap, console

I need to configure a IMAP4 capable (console-based) email client to 
- check and edit the name of an attachment ("contains umlauts?" -> change character ä to ae)
- delete emails that don't fit certain requirements (not PDF, DOC,... not from domain xyz.com)

Whether the client can do everything by itself or can just trigger a script on incoming mail doesn't matter.

Anyone have an idea with mail client would be suitable for such a task?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research I found a good program which can solve my problem with only a little LUA scripting.

http://imapfilter.hellug.gr/

Answer (score 0):

That's better done at the mail server level, attempting to do it at the client end just opens up race conditions.

Filtering attachments can easily be done with something like Anomy Sanitizer:

http://mailtools.anomy.net/